# How do I write a program which give me all prime ideals with norm up to 3?

Tags: computational-mathematics, sagemath

The program should give me all prime ideals in the ring of integers up to norm 3. So far I have:

```
sage: K.<a> = QuadraticField(-23) 
sage: L=K.ideals_of_bdd_norm(3)
     if L.is_prime()
        print L
```

but this does not work.

Comment: This sounds like a good question for ask.sagemath.org.  You'll also want to be more clear about what "does not work", as it's hard to tell from the way you word your question whether it finds too few, too many, or just crashes.

Comment: Also asked as Ask Sage question 51803: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/51803